# Trouble with pagecontainer (jQuery Mobile)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, cordova

I'm developing an app with PhoneGap but there is an issue. I have a log in form, and, as it is very simple, I'm sending the login information on the URL. 
So, that's what happens: User puts username -> jQuery changes the page to logged_in.html (pagecontainer) and then loads www.example.com/logged.php?user=USERNAME_ON_FORM. 
However, the logged_in.html page does load, but somehow it is keeping the old page, so I have to scroll down to see the logged in page. Is there anyway to work this out?
I tried this but it disabled everything.

```
$(document).bind("mobileinit", function () { $.mobile.ajaxEnabled = false; });
```

Here it is my code:

```
var $ = jQuery.noConflict();

$(document).ready(function(){



function init() {
document.addEventListener("deviceready", deviceReady, true);
delete init;
}


$("#loginForm").on("submit",function(e) {
var u = $("#username", this).val();
if(u != '') {

 // $.mobile.changePage("logged_in.html");
 $("body").pagecontainer("change", "logged_in.html" );


             setTimeout(function(){
             $('#logged_teste').load('http://example.com/app/model/login_dados.php?email='+u);
            },1000);

}
return false;
}); 
});
```

I'm searching for anything I can do but nothing works...

Comment: try ($( ":mobile-pagecontainer" ).pagecontainer( "change", "logged_in.html", { transition: "none" });)

Comment: @Tasos it still loads in the same page. :-(. I noticed there is this div: 
<br>
<div data-role="page" data-url="/login-card.html" tabindex="0" class="ui-page ui-page-theme-a" style="min-height: 651px;"> OLD PAGE CONTENT </div>

Comment: How are your Pages constructed, i mean the HTML. can you post that in your question

Comment: Hi Tasos, thank you for the help. I solved it by instead of changing the page and then loading, simply loading in the same page. Thank you for helping me out!